# How to check if a value is binary or not

Tags: python, binary, converters

I'm making a program that converts binary to octal, decimal, and hexidecimal values. How do I check if the user's input value is a binary number or not? 
Here's the code:

```
def repeat1():
    if choice == 'B' or choice == 'b':
        x = input("Go on and enter a binary number: ")
        y = int(x, 2)
        print(x, "in octal is", oct(y))
        print(x, "in decimal is", y)
        print(x, "in hexidecimal is", hex(y))
        print(" ")
        def tryagain1(): 
            print("Type '1' to convert from the same number base")
            print("Type '2' to convert from a different number base")
            print("Type '3' to stop")
            r = input("Would you like to try again?")
            if r == '1':
                repeat1()
            elif r == '2':
                loop()
            elif r == '3':
                print("Thank you for using the BraCaLdOmbayNo Calculator!")
            else:
                print("You didn't enter any of the choices! Try again!")
                tryagain1()
        tryagain1()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't post links or images.  Cut and paste the actual code in the question so people can do the same to run your code and/or alter it for an answer.  See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: A binary number has to consist of 0 and 1. From here, it is up to you. If you say the number is binary, it is binary. For example 101101011 consists of 0 and 1, but it can be decimal, hexadecimal, binary or some other.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Thank you for that, will improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a number is in binary, there are two steps: Check if it is an integer, and check if it contains only 1s and 0s.

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter binary number"))
    except ValueError: # If value is not an integer
        print('Must be a binary number (contain only 1s and 0s)')
    else:
        # Iterates through all digits in x
        for i in str(x):
            if i in '10': # If digit is 1 or 0
                binary = True
            else:
                binary = False
                break
        if binary == False:
            print('Must be a binary number (contain only 1s and 0s)')
        else:
            break # Number is binary, you are safe to break from the loop
print(x, "Is Binary")
```

The user is asked to input a number, and the program tries to convert it to an integer. If the program returns a `ValueError`, this means the input is not an integer, and the program will print that the number is not binary, and the while loop will start again. If the number was converted to an integer successfully, the program will iterate through the number (you have to convert to string as integers are not iterable) and check if all the digits in `x` are `1` or `0`. If a digit is not, the variable `binary` will change to `False`. When the program has successfully iterated through the whole value, and `binary` is `True`, it breaks from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isBinary(num):
    for i in str(num):
        if i in ("0","1") == False:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: what if `num` is not converted to an integer?

Answer (score 0):

I think `try-except` is the best way. If `int(num, 2)` works, then `num` is binary. Here is my code:

```
while True:
    num = input("Number : ")
    try:
        decimal = int(num, 2) # Try to convert from binary to decimal
    except:
        print("Please type a binary number")
        continue              # Ask a new input

    binary = bin(decimal) # To prefix 0b
    octal = oct(decimal)
    hexadecimal = hex(decimal)

    print(decimal, binary, octal, hexadecimal)
```

Example output:

```
Number : john
Please type a binary number
Number : ...
Please type a binary number
Number : 12546
Please type a binary number
Number : 10000101011
1067 0b10000101011 0o2053 0x42b
Number : 100111011
315 0b100111011 0o473 0x13b
```